# iOS: get date and time from separate pickers and add them together?

Tags: ios, cocoa, date, picker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSDateComponents of an NSDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478651/nsdatecomponents-of-an-nsdate)

I have set up two `UIDatePicker`s in InterfaceBuilder: one of them has it's mode set to "Date", and the other one's mode is set to "Time".

I have successfully taken the date from the "Date" picker in my ViewController, but it comes with a time...

My question is: how can I use both pickers to get a single date?

[image: the "Date" picker and the "Time" picker]

(for those of you wondering why I'm not using the "Date and Time" mode: this wouldn't make it easy for a user to select a year)

Many thanks,

Comment: Someone may find useful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597500/how-to-combine-date-and-time-from-two-uidatepickers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the documentation for NSDate and NSDateComponents.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470