# How to combine date and time from two UIDatePickers?

Tags: iphone, ios, uidatepicker

I have two `UIDatePickers` in my app, one mode is for selecting date and other to time mode. I have fired a notification when the exact date and time is reached. I'm able to fire the reminder at correct time, but the problem is that the date is not checked. Is there any way to check the date and time at the same time??

Thanx in advance...

Edit

```
NSDate *date1 = [datePicker date];
NSDate *date2 = [timePicker date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

unsigned unitFlagsDate = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [gregorian components:unitFlagsDate fromDate:date1];
unsigned unitFlagsTime = NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit ;
NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [gregorian components:unitFlagsTime fromDate:date2];

[dateComponents setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
[dateComponents setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];

NSDate *combDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponents];   

UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil) return;
NSDate *fireTime = combDate;
localNotif.fireDate = fireTime;
localNotif.alertBody = @"Alert!";
localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;  
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
```

Comment: There are so many result for this http://www.google.co.in/search?q=objective+c+complare+date+and+time&aq=f&oq=objective+c+complare+date+and+time&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&tbo=d&spell=1&q=objective+c+compare+date+and+time&sa=X&ei=BrUIUaruHInprQeL-4DwDg&ved=0CC4QvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41642243,d.bmk&fp=262c79f7a17c7860&biw=1279&bih=576 what is your problem for which u r not getting soluction there?

Comment: @CRDave: I tried so many methods. But I repeatedly getting the combined date as 2001-01-01 or so. and the notification comes at the time is saved.

Comment: Put some line of current code like in which format u get date n time. as NSString or as NSDate and how u r combining. I hope it will help someone to help u back.

Comment: @CRDave i think you read it incorrectly, its not comparing,its combining date and time..

Comment: Have you connected your IBOutlets up, because I copied your code and I get the correct date and time in dateComponents (after you do setHour and setMinute).

Comment: @rdelmar: i have rechecked my iboutlets. they are ok..

Comment: Try logging date1 and date2 to see what they return (I got  2001-01-01 for the date when my date picker wasn't hooked up properly).

Comment: @rdelmar: i am also getting the same date.. and i dont have iboutlet for the datepicker because i created it programmatically..

Comment: need more explanation...

Comment: Explanation on which part?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:self.datePicker.date];
NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:self.timePicker.date];

NSDateComponents *newComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
newComponents.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
[newComponents setDay:[dateComponents day]];
[newComponents setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
[newComponents setYear:[dateComponents year]];
[newComponents setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
[newComponents setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];

NSDate *combDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:newComponents]; 

NSLog(@" \ndate : %@ \ntime : %@\ncomDate : %@",self.datePicker.date,self.timePicker.date,combDate);
```

Comment: DEPRECATED - 8.0
NSCalendarUnitYear, NSCalendarUnitMonth, NSCalendarUnitDay
NSCalendarUnitHour, NSCalendarUnitMinute, NSCalendarUnitSecond

Answer (score 5):

`Swift 5` version of the accepted answer if it might help.

```
/// Returns `Date` from date and time.
func combine(date: Date, time: Date) -> Date? {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: date)
    let timeComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: time)
    
    var newComponents = DateComponents()
    newComponents.timeZone = .current
    newComponents.day = dateComponents.day
    newComponents.month = dateComponents.month
    newComponents.year = dateComponents.year
    newComponents.hour = timeComponents.hour
    newComponents.minute = timeComponents.minute
    newComponents.second = timeComponents.second
    
    return calendar.date(from: newComponents)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Convert date into NSString and Time into NSString.

Apppend Time into date string.

Now convert that final string into NSDate

Example: (Add validations from ur side)

```
 NSDate *date1 = [datePicker date];
    NSDate *date2 = [timePicker date];

    NSString *date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",date1];
    NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",date2];

    NSString *dateAndTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",date,time];
    NSDate *dateTime = [self dateFromString:dateAndTime];



- (NSDate*) dateFromString:(NSString*)aStr
{


    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];
    //[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss a"];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

    NSLog(@"%@", aStr);
    NSDate   *aDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:aStr];
    [dateFormatter release];
    return aDate;
}
```

Comment: after lots of struggle , the above logic works fine for me