# how to add calendar event on specific time and date?

Tags: ios, swift, date, time, ekevent

- i get date and time from date-picker and i have set it **into string** format.
- i want to add event in given date and time.
- i want to set two alert, **1** alert on before given specific time like "5 minute, 15 minute, 30 minute". **2** second alert on event time.
- In below code what should i need to do for complete my requirement.

give any suggestion or idea to solev it
**Thanks**

get date and time from date-picker

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"
    routineDate = dateFormatter.string(from: self.datetimepicker.date)
    print(routineDate)

  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm a"
    routineTime = dateFormatter.string(from: self.datetimepicker.date)
    print(routineTime)
```

create and save EKEvent Here:

```
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"
    let startDATE = dateFormatter.date(from: routineDate)
    let endDATE = dateFormatter.date(from: routineDate)

    print(routineDate)
    if temptypeID == "1" {
        let event:EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: appleEventStore)
        event.title = tempDescription

    //  what should i need to change here for specific date and time?

        event.startDate = (startDATE?.addingTimeInterval(60*60))!
        event.endDate = (endDATE?.addingTimeInterval(60*60))!
        event.isAllDay = false
        event.notes = "This is a note"
        event.calendar = cal

        do {
            try appleEventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
            print("events added with dates:")

         // what should changes i need to do here for alert ?

            let alarm = EKAlarm(absoluteDate: Date(timeInterval: -3600, since: event.startDate))

        event.addAlarm(alarm)

        } catch let e as NSError {
            print(e.description)
            return
        }
        print("Saved Event")
    }
```

Comment: You are getting a date from the datePicker. Why are you formatting to a String to save it and then formatting it back to a Date to use it? I would save it as a Date and format it to a String only for display purposes (like showing it on a UILabel)

Comment: i know that but what should i do for my solution ? @pesch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try saving your dates as Date:

```
let startDate = self.datetimepicker.date
let endDate = startDate.addingTimeInterval(3600 as TimeInterval)
```

Then use these to create your event:

```
let event:EKEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: appleEventStore)
event.title = tempDescription

//  what should i need to change here for specific date and time?

event.startDate = startDate
event.endDate = endDate
event.isAllDay = false
event.notes = "This is a note"
event.calendar = cal

do {
    try appleEventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
    print("events added with dates:")

    // Adding an Alert 1 hour before the startDate
    let reminder = EKAlarm(relativeOffset: -3600)
    event.addAlarm(reminder)
    print("Saved Event")
} catch let e as NSError {
    print(e.description)
    return
}
```

Also, the creating of your event should not be inside your DateFormatter declaration.

Comment: as per your answer it set only time into event.  what for specific date and time for event ? i have two date picker, one for date and one for time. both are separated(see my code). i want add event for one time like : (19-may-2017  and time is 5:15 pm). so how can i do this ? please help me

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597500/how-to-combine-date-and-time-from-two-uidatepickers

Comment: above your reply help me and save my time also. can you help me to add alert in event ? i want two alert as mention above in my question

Comment: I added this: 
    `let reminder = EKAlarm(relativeOffset: -3600)`
    `event.addAlarm(reminder)`
let me know if it worked for you

Comment: its not working. Even when i not set any alarm to event and save event then i check in iphone calendar app it show me one alert for 5 min before that not setteds by me. so why it take alert as 5 minutes before by default.  i want set alert base on my requirement.

Comment: what are you using for `appleEventStore`? I believe the problem might be there. Also, you have to include `NSRemindersUsageDescription` and `NSCalendarsUsageDescription` in your `info.plist`. Look here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/eventkit/ekeventstore

Comment: i already added both  NSRemindersUsageDescription and NSCalendarsUsageDescription in info.plist file and appleEventStore its just variable name for EKEventstore

Comment: Have you requested access? https://developer.apple.com/reference/eventkit/ekeventstore/1507547-requestaccess

Comment: do you know help me to add custom frequency on event like i want to add weekly frequency, in which user can select multiple day like user can add event on every Monday and Friday or it can be all day or only one specific day like Saturday. i having array of selected day.

Comment: There is no method for this in `EKAlarm`, you will have to build it in UI. Once you have an array of dates for your alarms, you can create EKAlarm instances looping through this array. Are you going to accept an answer? :)

Comment: thanks for answer related to alarm, But my last comment is new things to do. its not related to alarm. its related to add event on specific day for every week. i just get day no. from user.

Comment: Are you setting the `organizer` property? This would be your "from user". Here's a link to the docs: https://developer.apple.com/reference/eventkit/ekevent/1507357-organizer

Comment: i'm not using organizer property but i' doing this open my question link :  http://stackoverflow.com/q/44111168/6638267        please Help